# Iterate through a string and remove a letter

Tags: scripting, string

I'm trying to remove some specifics characters from a string. The idea is that the user inputs permissions and a file name and I remove the bad permissions (those not being `r`, `w` or `x`). My script would be as it follows:

```
permisos=$1  
for i in `seq 1  ${#1}`; do  
        perm_actual=${1:i-1:1}  
        [[ $perm_actual != *"r"* ]] && [[ $perm_actual != *"w"* ]] && [[ $perm_actual != *"x"* ]] && echo "El permiso $perm_actual es incorrecto, ignorándolo..."  
        permisos=${permisos/perm_actual/}  
done  

chmod u+$permisos $2
```

Does anybody know why is not removing the bad permissions from the variable `permisos`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm so sorry, I don't know how to properly format text. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 4):

Removing letters from strings is easy to do in one go without iterating over the characters of the string.  This could be done with `tr` like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

perms="$( printf '%s' "$1" | tr -c -d 'rwx' )"

chmod u+"$perms" "$2"
```

This uses `tr` to first remove everything from the first command line argument that is not any of the characters `r`, `w`, or `x`, then it performs the `chmod`.

Note the quoting of the expansions, especially `"$2"`.  Without these quotes, you would not be able to use your script on files with spaces or filename globbing characters in their names (see e.g. "[Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766)").

In `bash`, you may instead use a parameter substitution like

```
perms=${1//[!rwx]/}
```

This removes everything that is not `r`, `w` or `x` from `$1` and assigns the result to `perms`.

The `bash` script then becomes

```
#!/bin/bash
chmod u+"${1//[!rwx]/}" "$2"
```

---

By using

```
shift
chmod u+"$perms" "$@"
```

where `$perms` is computed in any of the above ways (*before* the `shift`), you could even get your script to perform the change on multiple files at once.  The `shift` removes the first command line argument form the list and `"$@"` will expand to the rest of the arguments, each individually quoted.

---

If you *absolutely need* to iterate over the characters of the string (you don't), then you may do so like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

string="$1"

for (( i = 0; i < ${#string}; ++i )); do
    ch="${string:i:1}"
    if [[ "$ch" == [rwx] ]] && [[ "$new_string" != *$ch* ]]; then
        new_string+=$ch
    fi
done

printf 'The new string is "%s"\n' "$new_string"
```

This builds a *new* string from the old by adding `r`, `w`, or `x` to it if the current character in the original string is one of those characters, and if the character does not already exist in the new string (not necessary for the operation of `chmod`).

Instead of using `seq`, we use a `for` loop running from zero to one less than the original string's length, and for ease of reading and to not repeat ourselves, we extract the current character into `ch` in each iteration.

Instead of three tests on the character, we perform a single pattern match to see whether it's `r`, `w` or `x`.

Answer (score 2):

`${permisos/perm_actual/}` removes the literal string `perm_actual` from the variable's value, I think you want `${permisos/$perm_actual/}` instead.

But you could just use `permisos=${permisos//[^rwx]}` instead of the loop to remove every non-`rwx` character at one go, and `[[ $permisos = *[^rwx]* ]]` to check if the variable has any of them.

<sub>(Both `${foo//bar}` and `[[ .. ]]` are nonstandard extensions, but you used them already so you're probably running Bash/ksh/zsh.)</sub>